# Apex cover get;set; in test class

Tags: unit-testing, apex

I have this class created:

```
public with sharing class CheckingClass{
    public String listObjects{
        get{
            if(String.isEmpty(listObjects)){
                listObjects = this.getListObjects();
            }
            return (listObjects);
        }
        set;
}
```

`getListObjects()`is a private method that gets a list of objects from database.

Point is that when I try to call the `listObjects` in my test class I can achieve to get through the `get`

**Test class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class CheckingClassTest {
    @istest static void test_method(){
        Test.startTest();
        CheckingClass chClass = new CheckingClass();
        chClass.listObjects;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

But it's giving me:

`classes/CheckingClassTest.cls: Expression cannot be a statement.`

**Does anyone knows how to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually accept that return value, you're trying to set it so

```
String aString = chClass.listObjects;
```